# Can you connect to a dnn website on a vm from the host vm

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, dotnetnuke, iis-express

I heard that you cannot connect to a dnn website made on your VM/webserver on your host pc.
But is that really true?

Comment: "a dnn website on your VM/webserver on your host pc"? What's that? Maybe you mean "a dnn website on your VM from your host pc"? Edit your question to make it clear and provide more details for others to review.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you have a DNN portal on computer A (which happens to be a VM) and that you'd like to browse to that website using computer B, then the answer is YES.

You need to have the networking set up correctly.  Generally that means that you need to have the DNS on computer B set up so that requests to computer A are routed correctly.  On computer A, the website needs to be configured to that IIS routes incoming requests to the DNN portal and the DNN portal needs to have an appropriate Portal Alias to complete things.

The easiest way to do this is by adjusting the hosts file on both computers, the bindings for the DNN portal in IIS, and the Portal Alias table in DNN.